# What makes a particular using directive unnecessary?

Tags: c#

I have a solution with multiple projects.

Project A has namespace 1 which uses a particular class X and has a using directive for it. That project compiles.

Project B has class 2 (in namespace 2) which uses the same class X but does not compile because "The name X does not exist in the current context". If I include the using directive from class 1 I get "Using directive is unnecessary"

So there is something different about project A and B, where one needs the using directive and one doesn't.

There are clearly multiple issues with my solution here but first I want to understand what makes a using directive necessary or not. Where can I start looking?

**Edited** to clarify the text above a bit, and also add the following code snippets as requested.

Project A:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure; //CloudConfigurationManager is here
using MyNamespace.MyClass; //Constants is here

namespace n1
{
   private static string resourceId = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("id");
   Console.WriteLine($"{resourceId}{Constants.Blah}("blah")";
}
```

Project B:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure; //directive unnecessary
using MyNamespace.MyClass; //directive unnecessary

namespace Testing
{
  class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string resourceId = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("id"); // The name CloudConfigurationManager does not exist in the current context
      Console.WriteLine($"{resourceId}{Constants.Blah}("blah")"; // The name Constants does not exist in the current context
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you please show some code, which is s short as possible but as long as needed to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I very rarely experience this too, my solution to this is to fully quality the affected class.

Comment: How class X is defined?

Comment: 1) If the other class is in same namespace, the using directive is unnecessary. 2) The namespace *in the `using` directive  *and** the class that you are trying to use must in a library referenced by the project. It's possible that your problematic project knows the *namespace* (because somehow it links some reference to it), but hasn't the reference to the particular class you are trying to use. This is a comment, because as already stated above, until you give more details on definitions of your classes and projects, this is pure speculation.

Comment: Static code analyser might be getting confused with class names and simply be wrong if your code doesn't compile when you remove said `using`. C# allows you to have `using ...; namespace ... { ...` and `namespace ... { using ... `. I recommend the later. Having `using`s inside namespace removes a lot of ambiguity.

Comment: @pmcilreavy In addition to vote you should also add a close-vote to the question for the exact same reason.

Comment: @pmcilreavy I don't see the criteria in your link specified in SO rules. Can you point me to an SO page that states why my Q is unacceptable? If I knew all the information required to answer my question then I'd know exactly where to look to solve my own issue and wouldn't need to ask it.

Comment: @andrea https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: OK so is a question like: "What makes a particular using directive unnecessary"? (which is just a factual question), not right for SO? I'm sure SO is full of such factual questions without reference to a particular problem someone is having - and some of these are now community wiki. Should I remove all reference to my reason for asking the question and just leave the bare question??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `using X` class X in your Project B separately. Your `using X` from `Project A` isn't forwarded by only adding a `using A`.

If you would only use functions/classes from `Class 1`, which encapsulate functionality of `class X` you would be OK with only referencing `class 1`.
But in your case, as I understand it, you want to use X-functionality directly - hence the separate using directive.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using A though, I'm using X. So 'using X' works in A, but not in B. So Im trying to understand the difference between A and B and where to look to find that difference.